# Basic I/O problems in Java

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

i am a total newbie at java. This code i wrote checks if an integer is an odd or even number. I ran into problems when i typed in a letter, error was basically it was expecting an integer, nothing else. My question is, how do i check if the input is a valid integer and nothing else before assigning i the value of inputChar?

Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Oddeven {
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

  System.out.println("Type in any integer");
  Scanner inputChar = new Scanner(System.in);

  int i = inputChar.nextInt();

  if (i != 0) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
      System.out.println(i + " is even");
      else {
      System.out.println (i + " is odd") ;
      }
      }
   else {
   System.out.println("Zeros are not allowed, bye!");
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Maybe something like `if (inputChar.hasNextInt()) { ... }`

Comment: You may use `try` block and catch exception about invalid int

Answer (score 2):

You should use

**inputChar.hasNextInt()**

and if this function return true then it means that the next input is an integer. If it returns false then that input is not an integer. You can use it in this way.

```
if(inputChar.hasNextInt())
{
 if (i != 0) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) 
      System.out.println(i + " is even");
      else {
      System.out.println (i + " is odd") ;
      }
      }
   else {
      System.out.println("Zeros are not allowed, bye!");
   }
}
else {
     System.out.println("Other than integer inputs are not allowed, bye!");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `try-catch` block for when you call `inputChar.nextInt();` and print "Not a number" if an exception is thrown (which is the case if a user types a letter).

Try this:

```
int i = 0;  
try
{
    i = inputChar.nextInt();
}
catch (InputMismatchException e)
{
    System.out.println("Not a number");
}
```

Comment: don't catch generic exceptions

Comment: What harm can that do, but nevertheless, I have changed it to `InputMismatchException`, which is what it throws.

Comment: Catching generic exceptions can be harmful and many a man-hour have been wasted tracking done errors due to this.  If this answer was for a experienced programmer I would not have picked up on it.

Comment: Well thank you for your advice then. I am an experienced programmer, and have been using the `Exception` class as the type because I never knew what the actual error that could be thrown was, and that all exceptions subclass that class.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073800/testing-debugging/beware-the-dangers-of-generic-exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

Use hasNextInt() to validate input from scanner.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Oddeven {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        System.out.println("Type in any integer");
        Scanner inputChar = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i;

        if(!inputChar.hasNextInt())
            System.out.println("Not a number");
        else{

            i = inputChar.nextInt();

            if (i != 0) {

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    System.out.println(i + " is even");
                else {
                    System.out.println (i + " is odd") ;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Zeros are not allowed, bye!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP is not asking for pos number, so your example will maybe confuse him.  Consider simplifying.

Comment: He just need to look up hasNextInt() usage ! Any way Im going to modify his code and paste it. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Oddeven {
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

  System.out.println("Type in any integer");
  Scanner inputChar = new Scanner(System.in);

  while (true) {
      Integer i=0;
      Object test = inputChar.next();
      if(test instanceof Integer)
      {
          i=(Integer)test;
          if (i == 0) {
            System.out.println("Zeros are not allowed, try again!");
            continue;
          }

          System.out.println(i + " is " + ((i % 2 == 0) ? "even" : "odd"));

      }
      else{
          System.out.println("Please Enter An integer");
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is my solution with infinite loop that breaks when user input 0 or when you terminate the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Oddeven {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        Scanner inputChar = new Scanner(System.in);

        int i;

        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Type in any integer:");

            if(!inputChar.hasNextInt()) {

                System.out.println("Not a number");
                inputChar.next();

            } else {

                i = inputChar.nextInt();

                if (i != 0) {

                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                        System.out.println(i + " is even");

                    else {
                        System.out.println (i + " is odd") ;
                    }

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Zeros are not allowed, bye!");
                    break;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ask if you don't understand something, hopefully it helps, cheers!